# Browser support for mixed background-position values

Tags: cross-browser, css

Since CSS2.1 it's possible to mix CSS background-position values like `background-position: center 20px` or `background-position: 200px bottom`.

Now I need to know how good this browser support is, because I heard that Opera version < 8 and the really early Firefox versions (around V1) had problems with or didn't support it.

Comment: The most useful site for such questions is http://caniuse.com/ - you can check for compatibility of any CSS/HTML feature there

Comment: @keaukraine: Not "any" feature... only new features. You won't find this sort of information there; the feature described here is many years old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browser support for this is perfect when you consider only the browsers and versions that matter in 2012. The versions of Opera and Firefox that you mention were released up to **8 years ago**!

That said, for history's sake:

- This change is listed in the [changelog for Opera 8](http://www.opera.com/docs/changelogs/windows/800). So yes, it was not supported in prior versions.
- Mozilla implemented it in Gecko 1.7 through [this enhancement](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=219829). Gecko 1.7 is used by Mozilla 1.7 and Firefox 1.0 (although it was probably in some late 0.9 builds as well). So, technically, Firefox has always had basic support for this change from its first stable release.
- KDE implemented it in KHTML, fixing [this bug](https://bugs.kde.org/91572). This was, of course, adopted in WebKit for Safari 1.3. Safari 1.2 and under do not implement this change.
- Surprise! IE has supported this syntax all along (at least since IE5.0 anyway), and I believe could have been part of the reason why the change was brought into CSS2.1 to begin with.

Note that slightly more recent versions may interpret `y x` values "correctly" when you mix units, when in reality [they're not supposed to](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html#propdef-background-position). But since you should be writing valid CSS in the first place, that shouldn't matter either.